# Facing issue to install node js

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I am facing an issue when trying to install nodejs. When checking the error it requires to upgrade libc6 but I cannot find any way to upgrade libc6 for Ubuntu 18.04.

The old nodejs version I have already uninstalled it with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Issue

```
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     nodejs : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have gone through these [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1608463/when-libc6-will-be-updated-for-ubuntu-18-04) & [link2](https://www.quora.com/When-will-libc6-be-updated-for-Ubuntu-18-04) & [link3](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/mdoyw6/how_to_upgrade_libc6_on_ubuntu_1804_without_using/) but I didn't get any help

Comment: Have you tried to install a minor version of node instead?

Comment: Initially, I was using an older version of Nodejs which worked perfectly fine. Since I have not upgraded the node in a long time so I uninstall it and then try to reinstall it. When trying to install I am getting the above error

Comment: You're running a very old operating system. Even if Ubuntu 18 were still in maintenance, that usually means they will continue to support packages that were shipped with it. The suggestion from your first link is to upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version. It doesn't sound like you did that. Whatever Node shipped with Ubuntu 18 should still work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using an older version of the node. To fix the issue permanently it requires Ubuntu upgrade

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: This worked for me also for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 0):

first update the repo sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install the packages using the command

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Once the package determines that you have some missing dependencies,run the following command to fix broken or missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I have already tried all the steps but it didn't work. The issue is was libc6 package

Comment: Did u try installing the stable version of node from the node js website itself ?

Comment: Yes I have tried it already

Comment: ChatGPT also gave me these commands and didn't work for me :/

Answer (score -1):

If you want to install the node version with any version with multiple versions. All in one solution and without any error.

Run below commands:

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

source ~/.bashrc

nvm -v
nvm install v14 <requier version like 14,16,18,>
```